# How I can access to getState() to the slice reducer in reduxtoolkit using typescript?

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

```
export const redirectUser = createAsyncThunk(
  "login/redirectUser",
  async (id, { getState, requestId }) => {
    const token = getState().LoginPageReducer.token;
  }
);
```

Getting Error "Object is of type 'unknown'" - in getState().

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that the `createAsyncThunk` function does not know the type of your store's state.  You can set the type by supplying generics to the function.

```
interface MyState {
    LoginPageReducer: {
        token: string;
    }
}

export const redirectUser = createAsyncThunk<any, number, {state: MyState}>(
  "login/redirectUser",
  async (id, { getState, requestId }) => {
    const token = getState().LoginPageReducer.token;
  }
);
```

Now `id` has type `number`, `getState()` has type `MyState`, and `token` has type `string`.

You can see more of the details for these typings [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/f7c5e5a51c19f47b728ecaa296054cf12e7ebbbc/src/createAsyncThunk.ts#L294).